# zf2 Zend Framework 2 paginator select columns from multiple table

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In zend frame 2, I want to retrieve the columns name and results from two tables.

In SQL I can write

```
Select user.name, course.mark from course JOIN user.id=course.user_id;
```

This would return me the name of user, and their mark

But in ZF2 when I want to get such result using use Zend\Db\Sql\Select; wont work. I am using use Zend\Db\Sql\Select since Pagination is being used.

```
 zf2 User Model


    public function fetchAll($pagination = FALSE)
{
    if($pagination)
    {
        // create a new Select object for the table album
        $sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->from('course');
        $select->join('user', 'user.id = course.user_id',
                array('user.name','course.mark')
        );
        // create a new result set based on the Album entity

        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Course());
        // create a new pagination adapter object
        $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
                // our configured select object
                $select,
                // the adapter to run it against
                $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
                // the result set to hydrate
                $resultSetPrototype
        );
        $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
        return $paginator;
    }
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Should I also create a User Model? At the moment, I have only CourseTable

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need the User Model as you are using `Course()` Class for the `resultSet()`.
2. Add this at the top of the page - 
   `use Zend\Db\Sql\Select`
3. ```
   $select = new Select('course');   //'course' is set as the primary table
   $select->columns(array('mark'));   //This is for getting 'course.mark' column
   $select->join(
           'user',
           'user.id = course.user_id',
           array('name')              //This is for getting 'user.name' column
   );
   ```
4. In Course Model, add the `public $name;` along with `public $mark;` (Course Model attributes ).

   Only then the `mark` key of `resultSet` array will have the value or it will be empty.

Rest of the code is fine.

I hope it helps someone.